# Arduino control multiple NRF24L01

Tags: arduino, radio-transmission

How can I achive that I control, lets say, three arduinos with relay on the end.
They will be communicating with nrf24l01, so there will be  One TX and Three RX. I want to open/close relay on those three arduinos depending which one i choose. For exp. when I press button 1 of 3 it will ONLY open relay on first arduino.

How should I use pipes then?

Comment: To get this right: You have four arduinos, three acting as slaves and one acting as a master controlling the relay(why do you actually need relays to controll the arduinos, you can do this much simpler)

Comment: What did you do so far? Since this is a pretty basic task, I think you didn't even try the first examples in the library. If so, get the nRF library, try the examples, try to modify them to fit your needs, then check if it works. If it doesn't, post the resulting code here and we'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that assigning one specific channel to each slave Arduino. Then the master just have to select the right channel for the slave Arduino you want.

I don't know what library you use but if you look at [RF24](https://github.com/tmrh20/RF24) you can use `setChannel()` API to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the pipe addresses according to the receiver you re talking to. Precisely use address which are close to each other ie let first four bytes of the addresses of all the Arduinos be same and only change the last byte.